# IN with more than one column is possible?

Tags: firebird

I have this SQL

```
Select A, B, D from T
Where not exists (select F, S from Z)
```

Can I do the same thing using `NOT IN` for more than one column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some databases (eg postgresql) have support for row values, where you can do something like `ROW(x, y) NOT IN (select f, s from z)`, Firebird unfortunately does not have row values, so you cannot have more than one column in an `IN` (or `NOT IN`).

However you can usually emulate it with a correlated subquery in the exists, eg:

```
SELECT A, B, D
FROM T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Z 
    WHERE Z.F = T.X AND Z.S = T.Y
)
```

Note that `EXISTS` doesn't care about the selected values, but just that one or more rows were produced, so the two columns you use in your select within the `EXISTS` are not relevant (it could just as well have been `1` as I used above).